What is the meaning of "trace of a form with respect to the Kähler form"?
I'm reading Fangyang Zheng's Complex Differential Geometry. I have a problem with terminology while reading the following lemma.

Lemma 7.22 (Lu's Inequality). Let $ (M, h) $ and $ (N, g) $ be Hermitian manifolds. For a holomorphic map $ f: M \rightarrow N$, denote by $ u $ the trace of the nonnegative $ (1,1)$-form $ f^{*} \omega_{g} $ with respect to $ \omega_{h}$. Then we have
$$\frac{1}{2} \square u \geq a u-b u^{2}$$
where $ a $ is a lower bound of the second Ricci curvature of $ h$, and $ b $ is an upper bound for the holomorphic sectional curvature of $ g$, and $ \square u $ is the complex Laplacian defined by $ \operatorname{Tr}(\sqrt{-1} \partial \bar{\partial} u) $ with respect to $ \omega_{h}$.
Proof. Let $ \left(z_{1}, \ldots, z_{n}\right) $ and $ \left(w_{1}, \ldots, w_{m}\right) $ be local holomorphic coordinates in $ M $ and $ N$, respectively. Then $ u $ is given by
$$u=\sum_{i, j=1}^{n} \sum_{\alpha, \beta=1}^{m} h^{i \bar{j}} f_{i}^{\alpha} \overline{f_{j}^{\beta}} g_{\alpha \bar{\beta}}$$
where $ \left(h^{i \bar{j}}\right) $ is the inverse matrix of $ \left(h_{i \bar{j}}\right)$, the map $ f $ is locally given by $ w_{\alpha}=f^{\alpha}(z)$, $ 1 \leq \alpha \leq m$, and $ f_{i}^{\alpha}=\frac{\partial f^{\alpha}}{\partial z_{i}}$.
......

I have probably guessed what "trace of a form with respect to the Kähler form" means. If $\eta=\eta_{ij}dz^i\wedge d\bar z^j$, then the trace of $\eta$ with respect to $\omega_h$ is
$$\frac2{\sqrt{-1}}h^{i\bar j}\eta_{ij}.$$
But I want to know if there is a precise definition for it, such as whether the trace of such definition only has a definition for $(1,1)$-form, whether we can find the trace of a form with respect to other differential forms, and whether my guess is an equivalent statement of its original definition. Any help would be appreciated!

Any non-degenerate $2$-form (i.e., whose top exterior power is non-vanishing) can be used to raise and lower indices of a tensor field using the formula you've given (analogously to musical isomorphisms associated to a Riemannian metric), and then a pair of covariant and contravariant indices can be contracted. Is that what you're asking?

Ted's comment should of course read $V^\otimes V^\cong V^*\otimes V$ at the end. Just to clear up any potential confusion.

@AndrewD.Hwang I understood what you mean. Finding trace is the process of contracting a covariant index and a contravariant index, but here are two covariant indices, so we need to use metrics to "pull the upper index down" and “push an lower index up”, and then contract it (find trace).

@TedShifrin Contracting a covariant index and a contravariant index is well-defined (independent of choice of basis), but here are two covariant indices, and the trace of a $(0,2)$-tensor $A$, $\displaystyle\sum_ia_{ii}$ is not well-defined (dependent of choice of basis), so we need to use metrics to "pull the upper index down" and “push an lower index up”, and then contract it (find trace). Is my understood correct?

Yes, that's right. I'm reposting my comment to correct the typo that I made when editing it the first time.
It might be worth thinking about why the trace of a square matrix (perhaps representing a bilinear form) makes sense. We know that the trace of a linear transformation is well-defined. We use the standard inner product on $V=\Bbb R^n$ (say) to view an $n\times n$ matrix as a linear map: $a^i_j=\sum g^{ik}a_{kj}$. So $\sum a^i_i = \sum g^{ik}a_{ki}$. The notion of trace will vary with the choice of isomorphism $V^\otimes V^\cong V^*\otimes V$.

Sometimes the following formula is useful: if $\omega$ is a Kähler form and $\alpha$ is another $2$-form, then there is a function $f$ uniquely defined by $n,\alpha\wedge\omega^{n-1}=f,\omega^n$. This function is in fact the contraction you are interested in, usually denoted by $\Lambda_\omega\alpha$. Alternatively, $f=\mathrm{Tr}\left(\omega^{-1}\alpha\right)$.
